# troca img com um click

Tags: javascript, html, css

Eu estou desenvolvendo um projeto mas preciso de um slider que troco de img somente quando receber um "click". Por exemplo: Eu click em um img e ela ira passar para outro e assim por diante. Algum de vocês poderia me ajudar com este problema ?

Comment: Olá Ruan. percebi que é novo aqui no fórum. Sempre quando tiver alguma dúvida de como fazer algo, poste o código do que vc já desenvolveu até o momento, para ficar mais fácil do pessoal entender e poder te ajudar!

Comment: @Leandro isso aqui não é fórum, parceiro. :)

Comment: Coloca ai no Google `Galeria de Imagem `